# verify md5sum on android

Tags: android, busybox, md5sum

I would like to offer a md5 verifier in my android app which compares the server md5 and the just created one on the device.
The output should be like correct or incorrect and not that the user has to compare the hashes.
I already found out that it's possible to get the hash on android via

```
/system/xbin/busybox md5sum /sdcard/Download/FILENAME
```

. Of cause I can print the output of the command to screen but that's not what I want.
Because I don't want to reinvent the wheel is something like that already available? SHA1 would be possible too, both hashes are available.

Please help!

Comment: What is your question? Do you want us to do your work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this method to calculate md5 inside of Android Application

```
private String getMD5(String file){
    String md5 = "";

    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        FileInputStream is = this.openFileInput(file);

        DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(is, md);
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int count;
        while ((count = dis.read(data)) != -1) {

        }
        byte[] digest = md.digest();

        for (int i=0; i < digest.length; i++) {
            md5 += Integer.toString( ( digest[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1 );
        }
        return md5;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return md5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With "the server md5" I guess you mean another file on the server containing an md5 hash.

So you could just download the md5 file, open it and compare the string inside with your calculated md5.